# Download file from linux server once it is created

Tags: linux

I recently started to work with Linux server, I am very new. My CUDA/C++ program solves 2D differential equation and writes down output every, say, 1000 time steps. It happens roughly every minute. Is it possible to automatically download files to my PC once they generated on the Linux server, or save them directly to my PC? This would significantly accelerate my work since now I have to wait for my program to finish all the calculations and then download it manually. I also typically use 6 GPUS at the same time, they produce output in different specified folders on the LINUX server (say, folders `0`, `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`)

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) as there is an overlap in administration facility from user's viewpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inotify

In Debian or Ubuntu install the package :

apt-get install inotify-tools

Create two script, first for reading new file in directory, second for copying file to your computer

**inotifywait_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to check :
DIR="./files"

while NEW_FILE=$(inotifywait -r -e create --format %w%f $DIR)
do
  # Sctipt executed when new file is created :
  ./script_cp.sh "$NEW_FILE"
done
```

Used inotifywait options :

-e : Listen  for  specific  event(s) only (here just creating event)

-r : Watch all subdirectories of any directories passed as arguments

--format : %w => Path %f => File

**script_cp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Copy file $1"
scp "$1" user@hostname:/path_to_save
```

You can use scp, rsync or other system to copying files

Comment: Thanks for you, but I have a question how can I do this via using sftp. As the Linux server that has the file I need to automatically download, I haven't direct access to it. So I ssh server X then ssh server Y then sftp server Z which has need file. How to make your steps. I new with Linux.